# Do I get any benefit on having a video card with no monitors?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have two video cards on my computer: an AMD R9 270x and an older Nvidia 8400 GS.
I have this setup because until yesterday I had 3 VGA monitors running, one in the AMD and two in the Nvidia. Today I purchased a bigger HDMI monitor and now I only have two monitors plugged solely in the AMD card. leaving the Nvidia with no monitors in it.

My question is: Do I get any benefit in leaving the Nvidia card plugged in?
Specifically the tecnologies that will only run on Nvidia cards such as PhysX.

Answer (score 2):

PhysX requires CUDA support, and it looks like the Nvidia 8400 GS is too old for that.

On the other hand, Nvidia seems to have released [three different revisions of that model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_8_series#GeForce_8300_and_8400_Series) with different specifications, so it would be important to know which one of these revisions your card actually is. Nevertheless, it looks like all three revisions would be clearly outclassed by the AMD R9 270x.

Given that Nvidia and AMD drivers don't always play nice together, I'd classify this set-up as "not worth the potential for trouble" and would remove the old Nvidia card and its drivers.

Comment: Mine Is the Rev 3.0, the picture is identical and has the HDMI output. I had this setup for more than 4 years with almost no conflict (nier automata exploded and Ubuntu didn't worked so well either) but if you say that I will notice no difference I might as well take it out.